# Firebase set service account into environment variables Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, environment-variables, firebase-admin, dotenv

I am trying to embed my firebase service account that initializes the admin SDK into an environment variable. I have created a .env file manually with the service account credentials:

```
type=service_account
project_id=xxx
private_key_id=yyy
private_key=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\aaa\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
client_email=yyy
client_id=aaa
auth_uri=aaa
token_uri=aaa
auth_provider_x509_cert_url=aaa
client_x509_cert_url=aaa
```

Reading .env file in `config2.js` file:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cfg = {};

dotenv.config({path: './firebase/.env2'});

cfg.port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

cfg.type = process.env.type;
cfg.project_id = process.env.project_id;
cfg.private_key_id = process.env.private_key_id;
cfg.private_key = process.env.private_key;
cfg.client_email = process.env.client_email;
cfg.client_id = process.env.client_id;
cfg.auth_uri = process.env.auth_uri;
cfg.token_uri = process.env.token_uri;
cfg.auth_provider_x509_cert_url = process.env.auth_provider_x509_cert_url;
cfg.client_x509_cert_url = process.env.client_x509_cert_url;

module.exports = cfg;
```

And I am reading the credentials in another file:

```
const Config = require("./config2");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(Config),
  databaseURL: 'xxx'
});
```

The app is not initialized, I do not think I set it up properly. I tried the method here as well but without any success: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: Why not just set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable instead, and then use `admin.credential.applicationDefault()`?

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka do you set that like `process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = { /* my creds */ }` ? Or is there a more idiomatic way? Using firebase function:config:set only takes lowercase env names.

Comment: I executed the code inside my project folder with PowerShell : $env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\service-account-file.json", but nothing happened, I still cannot use admin.credential.applicationDefault()

Comment: You need to set it in the environment so that any running process can see it. On Linux you'd do `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/to/file.json` or add it to a bash profile or something. What errors are you getting?

Comment: on Powershell, I am not getting anything after I execute the code. Could I execute the Linux code on Git Bash as well on the project folder?

Comment: [@IsaakNewton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11269090/isaak-newton) Have you found how to store service account in .env here, I am facing same problem

Comment: @SmitGajera Unfortunately, I did not find a way.

Comment: @IsaakNewton I stored my service account file path in my .env file and it works for me